# Java - How to add the first value of an array with the last one and so on

Tags: java, arrays, logic

I need to add the value in the position 0 of an array with the last position, the value in the position 1 with the second to last and so on...

**Example:**

1: 8

2: 6

3: 4

4: 2

5: 1

6: 7

7: 3

**Result:** 11, 13, 5, 2

The size of the array is declared by the user when he runs the program and so are the values.

```
package act4p1;
import java.io.*;
public class Act4p1 {

public static BufferedReader entrada = new BufferedReader (new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        int tam;

        System.out.println("Cantidad de los elementos del arreglo: ");
        tam = Integer.parseInt(entrada.readLine());
        int[] arreglo = new int [tam];

        System.out.println("Teclea los "+tam+" valores");

        for (int i = 0; i < arreglo.length; i++) {
             System.out.print(i+": ");
             arreglo[i] = Integer.parseInt(entrada.readLine());
        }

        //Code needed here

        System.out.print("\nElementos del arreglo: ");
        for (int x = 0; x < arreglo.length; x++) {
            System.out.print(arreglo[x] + ", ");
        }


    }

}
```

Comment: Do you have any code, how would you do it without a computer?

Comment: Stack Overflow is not for asking people to write your code for you.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is code writing request.

Comment: `//Code needed here` is 100% correct, we still need to see your code writing attempt which should be put there. Remember that according to http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic 3. Questions asking for homework help must include a *summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem*, and a *description of the difficulty you are having solving it*.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you could that with a function as such:

```
public int[] sumFirstLastArray(int[] input)
{
    int inputSize=input.length; // length gives the array size
    int outputSize=(input.length+1)/2; //to get 1 more space if input is odd
    int[] output= new int[outputSize]; // initializes the result array

    for(int i=0;i<inputSize/2;i++)
    {
        output[i]=input[i]+input[inputSize-i-1];
        // inputSize-i-1 gives the ith last position of the array.
        // the -1 is necessary due to the array being from 0 to inputSize-1
    }

    if(inputSize%2==1) //check for odd input arrays
    {
        output[inputSize/2]=input[inputSize/2];
        //copy the middle element
    }

    return output;
}
```

The comments explain the logic behind this function. As for getting the input, it depends on what you're using for getting the input.